# Why can't transactions be sent directly to validators/mining pools?

Tags: ethereum

Now 99% of all interactions with the blockchain occur through Infuria or Alchemy (MetaMask - API Infuria).

Nobody raises their geth nodes.

Because of this, most people are skeptical about the word "decentralization", since the application still has a point of failure.

Why is it impossible to send transactions directly from the browser to the validator? What prevents this?

After all, this is the last obstacle before decentralization. If the browser/extensions stored hundreds of addresses of mining pools to which you can send a transaction, then such an application is almost fail-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a signed transaction is sent from a wallet software to a node (in the peer-to-peer Ethereum network) that broadcasts it to the rest of the network as a "transaction waiting to be mined" (i.e. placed in a mempool).

Miners usually take transactions from the mempool and place them in blocks.

It is technically possible for a miner to accept a transaction from another source (or create and sign it themselves), and place it in a block.

But it comes with an inconvenience for the transaction sender - they need to wait until this specific miner mines a block containing their transaction. If they sent the transaction to the mempool instead, any miner could have picked it up and include in their block. And there is currently no standardized way of sending a transaction to the miner directly - so each might have a different channel and different rules.

So to answer your question:

> *Why can't transactions be sent directly to validators/mining pools?*

They can. But it's just faster (for the transaction sender) to use the mempool and let the transaction be mined by anyone, instead of waiting for one specific mining pool to mine a block.

Comment: Thank you, then you can clarify the question. Is it possible to send a transaction to a mempool using HTTP/TCP/RPC method from the browser?

Comment: Any transaction sent to a normal Ethereum JSON-RPC endpoint is sent to a mempool.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa In JSON-RPC I see a point of failure. I want DApp users to work directly with validators' IP addresses.
And who controls mempool? Does it turn out to be some kind of centralized server?

Comment: You can send it directly to miners IP address if you 1) know the miner 2) they accept JSON-RPC calls. However zero miners accept this, so you need to provide a JSON-RPC node somehow. Also if you are looking for decentralised JSON-RPC hosting please check out https://pokt.network/

Comment: I will also suggest you to study basic Ethereum architecture, as understanding and discussing about the subject might require you to gather some prior knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The Pokt Network project is interesting, but it's still one URL for accessing the eth-rpc.blockchain.gateway.port.network and so this is a potential point of failure of my application. If they forget to renew the domain, if they forget to renew their server, if they disconnect, my application will stop working. 
I am looking for an option to work directly with the blockchain. Now this is the main goal to convince people that a decentralized blockchain is a real decentralization, and not a layer between web2 and web3 through a centralized JSON-RPC server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late reply, but in case you didn't get the answer you were looking for...

Connecting to the mempool directly is like connecting to a JSON-RPC endpoint. You're connecting to one node in the network which could go down. There really isn't difference. There is no central server there is just nodes connecting to nodes. Any site with the appearance of a central server is mostly just managing a list of nodes.

If you want decentralisation you need to understand the reality that nodes do go down. You need to bake redundancy into your app just like the network does.

What I mean is, why not keep a list of JSON-RPC endpoints with which you trust (in terms of not capturing and storing your requests for other uses, and their stability) in your app. Bake in some functionality to check endpoints before you use one to make sure it is up, if not move to the next in your list. If one isn't up, flag it as one to check when you can. When you get notified of this maybe it's a good time to check your lists.

Chainlist.org has a list of JSON-RPCs for various networks and provides states on them. I'm not sure if they offer the ability to pull lists from them via an API, but then you are creating that single point of failure you are talking about.